# Is GUI Testing is possible using Selenium if possible than whats is the best solution

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, selenium-rc

Is GUI testing is possible using selenium.

Currently we are developing our selenium scripts only for functional Testing, Now i have to use selenium for my GUI testing, So is that possible using selenium we can check the UI.Please let me know the solution how to integrates this

Comment: You will have to explain your definition of GUI testing. Selenium is good for user interface driven testing, functional or not :)

Comment: I am talking about  images,object properties,weather 
the screens are user understable or not,font 
size,colour. So its possible to use selenium for that

Comment: There are other GUI tools that can do better GUI Map comparison. Most rendered elements can be inspected vi UI element locator and also see the following links: http://njgibson.co.uk/selenium-ui-map/ & http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/GUI_Map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain aspects of UI testing like [usability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usability_testing), localization, layout etc can't be tested completely without manual intervention. You should depend upon manual testing for these kind of stuff.